# How to use ListView with custom object in QML?

Tags: listview, pyqt, qml, qobject

Currently I'm working with the QT-framework via PyQT. I have created a custom object (inheriting from QObject) and can use it as expected from QML. I have also created a delegate in QML, which takes care of the visual representation of this object and is also working as expected.

However, now I want to show a list of several of these objects (with the presentation as defined in the delegate) in a ListView (in QML again). I cannot seem to figure out how this is possible, so can someone give me some pointers?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Edit: In response to some reactions I'll try to clarify what I want to achieve a little bit more with an example. Here we have a rectangle (this is just for clarity purposes, normally this would be my custom object) with a single custom attribute (customText) and a delegate which simply defines the layout, both of which are working.

```
ListView {
    height: 1000
    model: Rectangle {
            property string customText: "1.jpg"
        }
    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: 200
        height: 200
        Text {
            anchors.fill: parent
            text: model.customText
        }
    }
}
```

However, now I basically don't want a single rectangle (which wouldn't make a lot of sense in a ListView), but several of them in for example a list. What I would expect is that I would have to change model to something like this, but then I get *"Cannot assign multiple values to a singular property "*:

```
    model: [Rectangle {
            property string customText: "1.jpg"
        },
        Rectangle {
            property string customText: "1.jpg"
        },
        Rectangle {
            property string customText: "1.jpg"
        }]
```

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Why don't you post here all the code related to the problem instead of _explaining_ it?

Comment: One way is to inherit from `QAbstractListModel` and define a model that gives away properties of each of these objects.

Comment: @folibis Because I tried quite a lot and I have no idea which code is closest to achieving what I actually want, so I think I'm actually looking for how QT is meant to solve this issue. However, I have now included a code snippet which should clarify the issue somewhat.

Comment: You can't create objects like this within the declaration of a JS array.. *how QT is meant to solve this issue* is to do as *Velkan* proposed - creating a descendent of `QAbstractListModel` that holds your data. The properties of the `QObject` that you have created should be transformed into `roles`.

Comment: Ok, according to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#model-prop) `model` could be either `ListModel`, `XmlListModel` or `VisualItemModel`. In your case `VisualItemModel` is more suitable for your needs .See [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-objectmodel.html#details) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ListModel` and `ListElement` qml types. Sample implementation for customized model :

```
ListModel {
    id: modelElement
    ListElement { customText : "1.jpg"}
    ListElement { customText : "2.jpg"}
    ListElement { customText : "3.jpg"}
    ListElement { customText : "4.jpg"}
}

ListView {
    height: 1000
    model: modelElement
    delegate: Rectangle { // You can use your custom object here
        width: 200
        height: 200
        Text {
            anchors.fill: parent
            text: customText
        }
    }
}
```

`ListElement` represent items in a list that will be displayed using ListView or Repeater items [Ref](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listelement.html#details).

You can define you custom object as `delegate` and then assign the `customText` to `Text` element.